# if libvirt storage volume encryption store secret key on hyper itself, how to protect the secret itself if attacker has physical access

Tags: libvirt

I want to encrypt our VM's disk in our KVM virtualization platform, and refer to: https://libvirt.org/formatstorageencryption.html#StorageEncryption.

We can do it as simple steps:

1. Create a secret
2. Create a encrypted volume
3. In VM definition, point to the secret uuid, like

```
    <disk type='block' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none' io='native'/>
      <source dev='/dev/vg/test-vm01'/>
      <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
      <encryption format='luks'>
        <secret type='passphrase' uuid='ebb28309-fb26-4a2a-a5a8-e25adea4bc8c'/>
      </encryption>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x06' function='0x0'/>
    </disk>
```

However, actually, libvirt stores the secret's value as base64 encode at /etc/libvirt/secrets on hyper, if attacker has physical access of hyper, he can easily get secret value.

I assume that hacker cannot get in remotely, but if having physical access, anyone can reset root password, then login hyper to get everything.

Is there any method?

Or this threat does not exist at all.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the attacker has root access on the local host, you've already lost. Even if libvirt encrypted its secrets on disk, the attacker can just grab the decryption key out of libvirtd memory. Or they can just access the guest VM memory to grab the LUKS master key directly.

The libvirt disk encryption is primarily designed to protect disk images when they are stored on network storage (NFS, etc). In this case it protects against a network MITM attacker, or an attack from the NFS server admin.  It can protect images stored on the local host when that host is powered off - assuming the main host root FS is also encrypted.

The only thing out of scope is protecting against root on the local virt host.

Comment: Hi Daniel, good point, I do think we should have a security boundary.

And, we should encrypt hyper's /etc/ folder to keep secret, and using tang server to open /etc/ automatically.

then, even attacker move the whole server out of our DC, he cannot get secret without tang server and passphrase of /etc/ folder.

Thank you very much, this answers question of my team.

Answer (score -2):

Even a network MITM can't be really stopped if non-trivial, as there are several methods to grab the decryption key then too.

It really isn't much one can do vs. non-trival (e.g. repeating), mitm attack, be it network, or local/(remote-local).